# Can't override Spree's helper's method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Why my code not overriding Spree's code?

**app/helpers/spree/frontend_helper_decorator.rb**

```
Spree::FrontendHelper.module_eval do

    def taxons_tree(root_taxon, current_taxon, max_level = 1)
      return '' if max_level < 1 || root_taxon.children.empty?
      content_tag :ul, class: 'taxons-list' do
        root_taxon.children.map do |taxon|
          css_class = (current_taxon && current_taxon.self_and_ancestors.include?(taxon)) ? 'current' : nil
          content_tag :li, class: css_class do
           link_to(taxon.name, seo_url(taxon)) +
           taxons_tree(taxon, current_taxon, max_level - 1)
          end
        end.join("\n").html_safe
      end
    end

end
```

Comment: Can you try renaming your file to `frontend_helper.rb`?

Comment: @MrShemek error: ```Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Spree::FrontendHelper```

Comment: Can you please change the first line to: `module Spree::FrontedHelper` (remove `module_eval` block)?

Comment: @MrShemek I've done so before. It leads to problem, that only my custom method works, but others from Spree::FrontendHelper not.

Comment: Then your original solution should work fine. Have you tried to restart the Rails server?

Comment: @MrShemek Of course, i restarted server after each change...

Comment: @MrShemek i've found out solution, see my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you have this in your `application.rb` ?

```
config.to_prepare do
  # Load application's model / class decorators
  Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../app/**/*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
    Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
  end

  # Load application's view overrides
  Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../app/overrides/*.rb")) do |c|
    Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
  end
end
```

Comment: no, why i should have it? is it any doc about this?

Comment: When you execute `rails g spree:install` is appended to application.rb. Check https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/generators/spree/install/install_generator.rb#L92

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Don't know why my application.rb miss this lines...

Answer (score 2):

**Look accepted answer above**

So it worked after i've added decorator file as require to initilizer:

**spree.rb**

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/helpers/spree/frontend_helper_decorator.rb"
```

To add all helpers decorator i use this code:

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/helpers/spree/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
```

**Don't forget to restart server after this changes!**